# Comparing dates in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to compare two dates from two different tables in oracle.

If both dates are equal then I should print dates are equal. If dates are not equal then I want to insert values to other table.

Suppose there are two tables namely, AAA and BBB

table AAA:-

| In_Date |
| --- |
| 2021-09-08 15:30:00 |

table BBB:-

| In_Date |
| --- |
| 2021-09-08 16:00:00 |

The date in table BBB can be either date or it can be null.

Below is the query which I have written,

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    aaa_date date;
    bbb_date date;
    emp_join date;
BEGIN
    select in_date into aaa_date from aaa;
    select in_date into bbb_date from bbb;
    if (aaa_date = bbb_date) then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EQUALS'); 
    else
    insert into emp_table values (aaa_date, bbb_date);
    end if;
END;
```

The above query is not comparing date, and also how to compare if there is date in aaa table but null value in bbb table.

Comment: What do you want to insert (a date from table AAA or a date from table BBB or both the dates) and what is the "other" table? Please, provide sample data and desired output for equality and inequality cases.

Comment: I want to insert both the dates to emp_table.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you don't need PL/SQL for such a *comparison*; if both tables contain only one row, you could

```
SQL> with
  2  aaa (in_date) as
  3    (select to_date('2021-09-08 15:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual),
  4  bbb (in_date) as
  5    (select to_date('2021-09-08 16:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual)
  6  --
  7  select case when a.in_date = nvl(b.in_date, sysdate) then 'equal'
  8              else 'different'
  9         end result
 10  from aaa a cross join bbb b;

RESULT
---------
different

SQL>
```

Note line #7 and `NVL` function which helps in case when `bbb` table doesn't contain value in `in_date` column.

Comment: Is it possible to use insert statement in case statement

Answer (score 0):

You do not need PL/SQL and can just use an `INSERT ... SELECT` joining the two tables:

```sql
INSERT INTO emp_table
SELECT a.in_date,
       b.in_date
FROM   aaa_date a
       INNER JOIN bbb_date b
       ON (
          a.in_date != b.in_date
       OR (a.in_date IS NULL AND b.in_date IS NOT NULL)
       OR (a.in_date IS NOT NULL AND b.in_date IS NULL)
       )
```

If you want to use PL/SQL then just wrap it in an anonymous block:

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO emp_table
  SELECT a.in_date,
         b.in_date
  FROM   aaa_date a
         INNER JOIN bbb_date b
         ON (
            a.in_date != b.in_date
         OR (a.in_date IS NULL AND b.in_date IS NOT NULL)
         OR (a.in_date IS NOT NULL AND b.in_date IS NULL)
         );
END;
/
```

Comment: I want to use PL/SQL

Comment: @ank12 Updated; just wrap the SQL statement in an anonymous block.

Answer (score 0):

The code does make sense only if both tables contain one row. If you want to compare dates from two different tables, with more than one row, you need to have something to compare with. Queries are inherently not ordered, so doing `select xx from xx` does not order the results.

Check this demo

```
SQL> create table testdate1 ( c1 date );

Table created.

SQL> create table testdate2 ( c2 date ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into testdate1 values ( to_date('01.01.2021 14:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into testdate1 values ( to_date('01.01.2021 15:00:00' , 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into testdate2 values ( to_date('01.01.2021 14:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into testdate2 values ( to_date('01.01.2021 16:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ) ;

1 row created.
```

If I select the tables without anything to compare them with, there is no guarantee I am comparing the same rows.

Let's add an identifier by using an `identity column`

```
SQL> alter table testdate1 add id number generated always as identity ;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table testdate2 add id number generated always as identity ;

Table altered.

SQL> select * from testdate1 ;

C1                ID
--------- ----------
01-JAN-21          1
01-JAN-21          2

SQL> select * from testdate2 ;

C2                ID
--------- ----------
01-JAN-21          1
01-JAN-21          2
```

Oracle will show date fields with the default format in the database, something you need to consider when you are comparing, mostly when you want to compare also hours and minutes, as in your example.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ;

Session altered.

SQL> select a.id , b.id , a.c1, b.c2 from testdate1 a inner join testdate2 b on a.c1 = b.c2 ;

        ID         ID C1                  C2
---------- ---------- ------------------- -------------------
         1          1 01.01.2021 14:00:00 01.01.2021 14:00:00


SQL> select * from testdate1 ;

C1                          ID
------------------- ----------
01.01.2021 14:00:00          1
01.01.2021 15:00:00          2

SQL> select * from testdate2 ;

C2                          ID
------------------- ----------
01.01.2021 14:00:00          1
01.01.2021 16:00:00          2
```

But if you have only one row, you can use a normal insert select ( as shown in another answers ).

If you want to use it on PLSQL

```
SQL> create table empdates ( c1 date, c2 date ) ;

Table created.

SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited
declare 
begin
 execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss''';
for h
in  
( 
  select a.id , a.c1, b.c2  ,
         case when a.c1 = nvl(b.c2,sysdate) then 'equal' 
         else 'different'
         end as result
 from testdate1 a join testdate2 b on a.id = b.id
) 
loop
    if h.result = 'equal' 
    then 
        dbms_output.put_line('id '||h.id||' has same date');
    else 
        insert into empdates values ( h.c1 , h.c2 );
    end if;
end loop;
commit;
end;
/

id 1 has same date

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from empdates ;

C1                  C2
------------------- -------------------
01.01.2021 15:00:00 01.01.2021 16:00:00
```

Comment: Do **NOT** use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE` data type. You are relying on implicit date to string conversion and it can fail [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=013c9c7e4c2cd251da3ff9f570db362d).

Comment: @MTO,, you are absolutely right. I modified the answer. thanks

Comment: How do I use the same in PL/SQL

Comment: @ank12, I edit the answer with a solution in PLSQL. Let me know if you have any other question

Answer (score 0):

You can use an INSERT statement with a condition containing inequality in order to compare the date values coming from each table such as

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO emp_table(aaa_date,bbb_date)
  SELECT a.in_date,b.in_date
    FROM aaa a
    JOIN bbb b
      ON a.in_date != NVL(b.in_date,date'0001-01-01'); 
  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN    
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EQUALS');
     ROLLBACK;
  ELSE
     COMMIT;   
  END IF;   
END;
/
```

where we'll get a message if there's no insertion

- Notice that a default value is used for `b.in_date` column to prevent
  the issue as using `!=` operator while the value is *NULL*
- The column value `a.in_date` is presumed to be *NON-NULL*, and both
  tables have only one row of data in any cases depending on the
  explanation within the question

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6adacc9626f50db0546eef664b3436ae)</kbd>